# Как быстро проверить длину коллекции в C#

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется коллекция неизвестной длины (очень большой), например, N. Можно ли проверить, имеет ли она длину M, не перебирая все N элементов, т.е. не используя Count() или Length?

Например.
Курсор идет по коллекции с начала в конец и считает, 1й, 2й, 3й, ..., M-2, M-1, ...! Идти по дальнейшим элементам, как делает Count(), не нужно!

Comment: Зависит о типа коллекции. Для каких то коллекций доступ к Length/Count будет очень быстрым, для каких то потребуется перебор.

Comment: Что понимается под словом "коллекция"? Это какой-то конкретный класс из FCL или какой-то абстрактный тип данных?

Comment: Если же "вообще" то если в вашем АТД есть счётчик, который при каждом добавлении данных инкрементит значение - то повторно проходить всё заново не надо. Пример - реализация односвязаного списка из head + count не требует обхода каждый раз, а без count - требует.

Comment: Под коллекцией понимается List, массив или таблица в БД.

Comment: Связные списки не рассматриваю.

Comment: List - Count, array - Length, Db - `select count * form table`.

Comment: Я не хочу брать ВСЕ элементы, можно как-то проверить, является ли он длиною M, не беря все N элементов коллекции, где N >> M.

Comment: Ответ можно. Определите свою коллекцию CountedList со счётчиком количества.

Comment: Чтобы сравнивать свое число с длиной коллекции, надо знать длину коллекции.

Comment: Мне надо узнать равна ли длина коллекции N (заранее неизвестная), длине M. Если N > M, то не перебирать оставшееся количество (M - N).

Comment: select count * form table - * означает взятие всех элементов, может как-то хранимой процедурой можно? Но лучше на C#.

Comment: `select count * form table` означает взятие только счетчика БД на таблицу, никакого перебора элементов тут нет - по сути БД должна просто взять индекс первичного ключа и вытащить оттуда количество элементов. Ничего, лкчше чем это, без указания БД вам никтьо не предложит. А если использзовать ORM, то ORM в лучшем случае такой же SQL сгенерирует.

Comment: Но ведь этот счетчик переберет все строки таблицы... Я понимаю что это все сверхбыстро в БД, но все же мне нужно посчитать так.

Comment: Этот счетчик (в том виде, что я показал) не перебирает строки таблицы. Почитайте про индексы БД, про планы запросов, выполните такой запрос у себя в БД и проверьте план.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Да беру "КОНКРЕТНУЮ" коллекцию, но такую, число элементов N которой я заранее не знаю, и при проверке равно ли оно M при N > M, мне надо перебрать в ней не больше М элементов. Эсли кто понял, то переформулируйте задачу по своему, может остальным понятно будет

Comment: Если у вас сомнения по поводу `select count * from table`, то вместо * вы можете указат ь свой первичный ключ. Это явно подскажет оптимизатору где брать результат, например `select count id from table`

Comment: Как раз хотел спросить про это, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример использования `Take()` для вашей задачи.

```
List<int> bigList = Enumerable.Range(0, 5000).ToList();

int lenght = 200;

bool hasLength = bigList
    .Take(lenght + 1)
    .Count() == lenght;
```

Comment: То,  что нужно !

Answer (score 5):

Массивы в .NET имеют свойство `Length`, которое имеет сложность O(1). То есть при обращении к нему не будет перебора коллекции.

Коллекции в .NET, реализующие интерфейс `IList<T>` или `ICollection<T>` имеют свойство `Count`, которое тоже имеет сложность O(1). При его использовании перебора не будет.

И лишь последовательности `IEnumerable<T>` при использовании метода `Count()` будут перебираться. Сложность O(n). С этим ничего не поделаешь. Единственно, можно ограничить количество перебранных элементов с помощью метода `Take(n)`.

Исходя из этого, если вам неизвестен тип коллекции (на входе `IEnumerable`), делайте приведение (кастинг) к `ICollection` - если приведение успешно, используйте свойство `Count`. Если неуспешно - значит это настоящий `IEnumerable` и перебор придётся делать. Напоминаю, можно ограничить его с помощью `Take`.

Для сведения: метод `Count()` внутри использует аналогичные проверки. Если он вызывается на `ICollection/IList` - его сложность будет O(1).

---

Каким образом вы приплели сюда работу с базами данных - вообще непонятно.

Как вам уже сказали в комментариях, запрос `select count(id) from table` использует индекс и перебора всей таблицы не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, стал лучше понимать.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью метода `Take()` из LINQ можно перебрать только указанное число элементов